# Unity: Can't access repeatDelay from StandaloneInputModule?

Tags: unity, input

I have a very specific problem. I'm trying to change the `repeatDelay` variable within my `StandaloneInputModule`, but it's not coming up as a variable. All of the other variables come up when I use `GetComponent<StandaloneInputModule>()`, but not the one that I want. Is there something different about `repeatDelay` that I'm not seeing?

EDIT: I'm using the `UnityEngine.EventSystems` namespace too.

Answer (score 1):

It was added in the 5.1 update. So download and upgrade your project and all should be good.